# .NET PropertyGrid: Accessing and manipulating Object instances at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I'm would like to access `object` objects through a PropertyGrid and have them behave as the actual things they represent. For a toy class such as;

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ObjectBucket.ObjectBucketConverter))]
class ObjectBucket
{
    public object foo;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public object Object
    {
        get { return foo; }
        set { foo = value; }
    }

    private class ObjectBucketConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string) ? true : base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
    }
}
```

i'd like to be able to set say a `float` through the Object accessor, and then have it behave as a `float` in a PropertyGrid, rather than the standard `object` behaviour of being able to do nothing to it.

As a work around I've put the following accessor in;

```
[Browsable(true)]
public string ObjectStr
{
    get { return foo.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(foo.GetType()).ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

which allows me to manipulate the object, but it not ideal. Is what I want to do even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You need to implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and supply your own instances of `PropertyDescriptors` (in `System.ComponentModel`) - in these property descriptors you can specify the property type - in your case float.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to implement your own typeEditor for the ObjectBucket.Object property.
That will allow you to show editor form where an user can specify the type and the value for this property in the following manner:
[image]

Here is the implementation skeleton:

```
class ObjectBucket {
    object foo;
    [Editor(typeof(ObjectUITypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public object Object {
        get { return foo; }
        set { foo = value; }
    }
}
//...
class ObjectUIEditor : Form {
    public ObjectUIEditor(object editValue) {
        /* TODO Initialize editor*/
    }
    public object EditValue {
        get { return null; /* TODO GetValue from editor */} 
    }
}
//...
class ObjectUITypeEditor : System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor {
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.IWindowsFormsEditorService edSvc = null;
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object objValue)
        if(context != null && context.Instance != null && provider != null) {
            edSvc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
            if(edSvc != null) {
                try {
                    ObjectUIEditor editor = new ObjectUIEditor(objValue);
                    if(edSvc.ShowDialog(editor) == DialogResult.OK) 
                        objValue = editor.EditValue;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        return objValue;
    }
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
        if(context != null && context.Instance != null) 
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        return base.GetEditStyle(context);
    }
}
```